# How to I install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 on a Debian-based system?

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I'm trying to install a .deb package with dpkg -i, but I get this error:

```
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of modelio-open-source4.1:
    modelio-open-source4.1 depends on libwebkitgtk-1.0-0; however:
    Package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is not installed.
```

So it seems I need to install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0. So I run `sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0`, but I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libwebkitgtk-1.0-0' has no installation candidate
```

How do I fix this? I really need this installed for school, and the clock is ticking...

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu you need to enable universe repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

[List of dependencies.](https://www.modelio.org/downloads-links/requirements.html#linux)

System requirement:

> Modelio 4 is compatible with Redhat Enterprise Linux 7/8, Debian 9/10 and Ubuntu 16.04/18.04 LTS.

> Modelio 3 is compatible with Redhat Enterprise Linux 6/7, Debian 7/8/9 and Ubuntu 14.04/16.04 LTS.

On PopOS you need the `18.04 LTS` release, to enable universe repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main universe"
```

Comment: I'm not on Ubuntu but I did this anyway and I got the same result. I'm on popOS

Comment: @DanielOscar I have added system requirement from the official website.

Comment: @DanielOscar Which version of popOS?

Comment: Pop!_OS 20.10, @GAD3R

Comment: They *claim* it’s compatible with Debian 10, but it isn’t :-(.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the official repos for the package across all versions:

- [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libwebkitgtk-1.0-0&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all)
- [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libwebkitgtk-1.0-0&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all)

You will notice that this package is not available in the newest releases.

You have three options:

- Have a binary which is packaged for the release you are using.
- Download the `libwebkitgtk-1.0-0` and install it manually (tedious).
- Modify your apt sources to include the old versions (not recommended).

Unless you go for the first one, you can hit recursive dependencies. It can actually be impossible to resolve the dependencies as the package is not made for your release.

On a side note: Try to set up your systes as soon as possible, especially when you need to rely on them. You never know which obstacles you may encounter. You do not want urgency. This is true for school, professional and private life.

Comment: when you say "Have a binary which is packaged for the release you are using", what do you mean? Can you explain this for a 2nd year CS student?

Comment: The developer chose to use a library called libwebkitgtk when they wrote the program. They assumed every user would have Ubuntu *release* 18.04. The library is available in the package `libwebkitgtk-1.0-0`. The human readable source was compiled into a machine executable *binary*. The binary needs the library. The binary was *packaged* into a .deb file. The package knows that the binary needs the library. You are using Pop!_OS 20.04 (which is similar to Ubuntu 20.04). This newer release does not offer libwebkitgtk. Either the developer adapts their code and .deb or you adjust your system.

Answer (score 0):

You might try `apt -f install`, which will try to fix the dependency problem either by downloading and installing necessary package(s), or by removing package(s) (one "removal" solution would be to remove the package you've installed).

To give a more detailed answer,
it would help to know what distribution you are running.

Comment: I'm running popOS. I did try that, but it ends up removing what I was trying to install instead of fixing dependencies

Comment: OK, so if it removed the package, that means the package you need is not available from the sources you have in your /etc/apt/sources.list file. What package did you originally install (maybe best to show the .deb filename, which has version info), and what package does it say it needs?

Comment: Cool. So now How do I add it?

Comment: The thing is, debian-based dists are sensitive to versions, so you need to find the version it wants. Installing a version that's earlier or later could break your package database, so you want to be careful before installing something an unknown version. So, if the version is not one for your version of popos, you need to find one that is, and I'm not totally sure how to do that for popos. (also, see edit of my prev comment, I have a couple question)

Comment: I downloaded the package "4.1.0_ubuntu_amd64.deb".